# Java GUI: None of my panels are showing up on my Frame, but its background color and title are visible?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I am creating a GUI-based Calculator program. I've separated the areas into panels, which have the ff purposes:

- inputPanel: Where users will input numbers;
- numericPanel: Panel that holds the digits 0-9
- operatorPanel: Panel that holds operator symbols(+, -, *, /)
- formatPanel: Panel that will hold CLEAR, ENTER, and EXIT buttons

I added all these panels to the frame before making it visible, but when I press play, nothing shows up except for the background color. Should I be formatting them a different way?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.concurrent.Flow;

/**
 * @author Graeven Yuri Videz
 * This is a program that simulates a simple calculator with arithmetic functions.
 */
public class calculator extends Frame implements ActionListener{

    private static JTextField firstField= new JTextField(25);
    private static JTextField num2 = new JTextField(25);

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private static JButton b0 = new JButton("0");
    private static JButton b1 = new JButton("1");
    private static JButton b2 = new JButton("2");
    private static JButton b3 = new JButton("3");
    private static JButton b4 = new JButton("4");
    private static JButton b5 = new JButton("5");
    private static JButton b6 = new JButton("6");
    private static JButton b7 = new JButton("7");
    private static JButton b8 = new JButton("8");
    private static JButton b9 = new JButton("9");
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private static JButton enterButton = new JButton("Enter");
    private static JButton clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
    private static JButton exitButton = new JButton("Close");

    private static JButton addB = new JButton("+");
    private static JButton subB = new JButton("-");
    private static JButton multiB = new JButton("x");
    private static JButton divideB = new JButton("÷");


    private static JPanel inputPanel;
    private static JPanel numericPanel;
    private static JPanel operatorPanel;
    private static JPanel formatPanel;

    private static JLabel resultLabel;
    private static JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Created by: Yuri Videz");

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void setInputPanel(JPanel panel) {
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JLabel firstNum = new JLabel("Enter your number:");
        panel.add(firstNum);
        panel.add(firstField);


    }

    public void setNumericPanel(JPanel panel) {
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 3));
        panel.add(b0);
        panel.add(b1);
        panel.add(b2);
        panel.add(b3);
        panel.add(b4);
        panel.add(b5);
        panel.add(b6);
        panel.add(b7);
        panel.add(b8);
        panel.add(b9);
    }

    public void setOperatorPanel(JPanel panel) {
        JPanel operatorPanel = new JPanel();
        //operatorPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        panel.add(addB);
        panel.add(subB);
        panel.add(multiB);
        panel.add(divideB);

    }

    public void setFormatPanel(JPanel panel) {
        JPanel formatPanel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        panel.add(enterButton);
        panel.add(clearButton);
    }


    public calculator() {
        inputPanel = new JPanel();
        setInputPanel(inputPanel);
        numericPanel = new JPanel();
        setNumericPanel(numericPanel);
        operatorPanel = new JPanel();
        setOperatorPanel(operatorPanel);
        formatPanel = new JPanel();
        setFormatPanel(formatPanel);

        setTitle("Calculator Program");
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
        frame.add(nameLabel);
        frame.add(inputPanel);
        frame.add(numericPanel);
        frame.add(operatorPanel);
        frame.add(formatPanel);
        setBackground(Color.gray);
        setSize(350, 500);
        frame.pack();
        setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        calculator calcuObject = new calculator();
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ac) {


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different `JFrame` instances in your code.
You add all components to `JFrame frame = new JFrame();` but you make the other one visible by `setVisible(true);`
Solution: 
change `setVisible(true);`  to `frame.setVisible(true);`
There is no need for calculator to extend `JFrame`.

---

Side notes: 
1. see [Java naming conventions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions/)
2. Follow this [link](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/nwtWItC9s5) for a refactored version of your code

Comment: exactly. He needs to have the main class *not* extend Frame and instead call `frame.setVisible(true);`

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't even realize that I'd done that and I feel like a dummy

Comment: Glad it helps. Don't fell bad. It happens to everyone.

Comment: @GRAEVENYURIVIDEZ: you also need to refactor that code as it is a bug-fest waiting to happen, including making ***all*** fields instance (non-static) fields, the only exceptions being constants

Comment: @GRAEVENYURIVIDEZ: also, up-vote this answer as well as accepting it